# Custom filtering

Tags: silverlight, filter, telerik-grid

Please suggest the best way for me. I want to change the default filter's behavior. I want my grid filter to work with all data from DB, not only with displayed data in the grid.

For example: 
I have 5 rows in the db-table (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
In the grid->ItemsSource i bound only 2 records (1 and 2)
when i click to the filter i want to see all records from DB (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and if i check 4 and 5 for example, grid gets from DB data and display selected in the filter rows (4, 5).

What is the best way for me to solve my tasks?

Thanks

Comment: I found many posts about custom filtering like this: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-filtering-custom-filtering-controls.html but this is only "client" filtering. I don't want to spend a lot of time to study internal telerik's controls behavior and override many methods. Maybe telerik's libs contain some ways to help me, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DomainDataSource will perform server-side filtering. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Can DomainDataSource work without RIA Services and Entity Framework? I use NHibernate + WCF (not RIA).

Comment: no. To do server-side filter with standard WCF, you'll have to define filters in your service definition.

Comment: I accepted answer but this way doesn't correlate with my source code. I wrote custom filter with custom events and added filters in my service definition without DomainDataSource...